# cluster multiple lines by slope in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my datasets, AP is name, D is time, V is value. I'd like to draw line plots for values over time for each name.

```
   AP   D  V
1 329   0 27
2 329  16 26
3 329  42 30
4 329  72 30
5 329 106 32
6 329 135 27
7 425   0 28
8 425  30 35
```

[image]

This is easy, just like below:
My question is:
Any possibility I could do polynomial fit/linear regression and group these lines according to SLOPE ?

Thx

Comment: What about obtaining first the slopes of each line say coef(lm())[2] and then cluster the slopes using e.g. kmeans()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to go about it, the first is to use the definition of slope in the context of OLS regression, i.e. [see formula at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Fitting_the_regression_line). Here I'm using `dplyr` to do the transformation, but you could do that in base R as well.

```
data_frame(x = rep(1:10, 10), 
           y = rnorm(100) - 0.5*x, 
           grp = rep(letters[1:10], each = 10)) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(slope = sum((y - mean(y))*(x - mean(x)))/sum((x - mean(x))^2)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_path(aes(group = grp, colour = slope))
```

The second way would involve doing it in a more flexible way with `broom`. Here's an example of that:

```
df <- data_frame(x = rep(1:10, 10), 
           y = rnorm(100) - 0.5*x, 
           grp = rep(letters[1:10], each = 10))

df.fit <- df %>% group_by(grp) %>% 
  do(tidy(lm(y~x, data = .))) %>%   # or other model
  filter(term == "x")
    # modify this line to select the correct term of your chosen model


full_join(df, df.fit) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_path(aes(group = grp, colour = estimate))
```

[image]